# Node v8.9.0 Error: Invalid key length crypto.createCipheriv

Tags: node.js

I have the following code that encrypt strings:

```
var crypto          = require('crypto'),
    algorithm       = 'aes-128-cbc',  
    key             = new Buffer('9vApxLk5G3PAsJrM', 'utf8'),
    iv              = new Buffer('FnJL7EDzjqWjcaY9', 'utf8');

function encrypt(text, key){
    /* GET - crypted */
    try {
        var cipher  = crypto.createCipheriv(algorithm, key, iv),
            crypted = cipher.update(text, 'utf8', 'hex');

        crypted += cipher.final('hex');
        return crypted;
    } catch(e) { return console.log(e)}
}

console.log(encrypt('blablabla', key))
```

And when i run this code in node v8.9.0 i get this error:

```
Error: Invalid key length
    at new Cipheriv (crypto.js:219:16)
    at Object.Cipheriv (crypto.js:217:12)
```

i try different key and iv lengths but i always get same error...so what it needs to be written key length?

I need to use crypto.createCipheriv because crypto.createCipher is depricied in new node version and new node version as describe developrs is 20% faster that previus version.

Comment: I don't see problem in your code. I have try it on my Node@8.4.0 and it work. Have you look if there are not an open issue. It look like a bug or a compatibility break.

Comment: ok thanks..i will try to post this in node section maybe is a bug in node 8.9.0 thanks for testing

Comment: Based on the docs, seems like `createCipherv` also accepts a key as a `utf-8` encoded string, so in theory you shouldn't need a `Buffer` at all - try passing the string directly in?

Comment: I try to pass direct string in it and same error...i think it is bug in node js 8.9.0 version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that i have old key from MySQL database that is whole time used as key and i defined globally key and therefore globally key is not used because MySQL read old encryption key and using 20 bytes length old MySQL database encryption key...using UPDATE in MySQL database i get new 16byte length encyption key and now is working.